# Unity tile doesn't drag unless cursor is at the edge of the piece

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial here, so not 100% of what my code is doing.  I am building out the ability to drag puzzle pieces around.  I had the code working, but then to fix the bug of the piece snapping to center the mouse, the instructor had me add an offset code:

```
private Vector3 offset;


private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
            if (hit)
            {
                draggingPiece = hit.transform;
                offset = draggingPiece.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            }
        }

        if (draggingPiece)
        {
            Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            newPosition += offset;
            draggingPiece.position = newPosition;
        }
```

Once I added the three lines of offset code, the piece only moves when my cursor gets to the edge of the piece as opposed to the piece staying fixed under the mouse pointer.  For example, if I click on the left side of the image and try to move it to the right, the mouse cursor first moves across the tile and only when it gets to the right edge does the piece start moving.  Any ideas?